# Meses FullCalendar PHP

Tags: php, javascript, fullcalendar

Pessoal estou usando usando o [FullCalendar](https://fullcalendar.io/) junto de uma consulta que tem alguns compromissos cadastrados em um banco de dados, só que peguei um problema que não sei resolver

Consigo fazer o calendar pegar os agendamentos do banco só que, os agendamentos do mês de novembro aparecem no mês de Dezembro.

Pelo que pude ver o **fullCalendar** tem um classe **css** chamada `data-calendar-month`, neste local ele define o numero do mês( mês 11,12 etc).

Por ele começar do 0 a contar os meses tem alguma influencia?

codigo:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
/*-----------------------------------------------------
Main Calendar
------------------------------------------------------*/
if($('#calendar')[0]) {
    var date = new Date ();
    var m = date.getMonth ();
    var y = date.getFullYear ();
    var target = $ ('#calendar');

    target.fullCalendar ({
        header: {
            right: '',
            center: 'm',
            left: ''
        },
        buttonIcons: {
            prev: 'calendar__prev',
            next: 'calendar__next'
        },


        theme: true,
        selectable: true,
        selectHelper: true,
        editable: true,
        eventLimit: 3,
        contentHeight: 900,

        events: [




        <?php  $i = 0; while($row = $calendario_todos->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) { ?>



            {


                id: <?php echo $row['id'];?>,


                title: '<?php echo $row['titulo'];?> ',


                start: new Date (<?php echo date('Y',strtotime($row['dtaInicio'])); ?>, <?php echo date('m',strtotime($row['dtaInicio'])); ?>, 


                    <?php echo date('d',strtotime($row['dtaInicio'])); ?>),


                allDay: true,


                color: '<?php  echo retornaCor(retornaDiaSemana(date('Y-m-d',strtotime($row["dtaInicio"])))); ?> ',



            },


            <?php  $i++;  } ?>



            ],
```

Comment: Como você está gerando os mêses? Poderia colocar o código?

Comment: porque você não gera um `jSon` antes de passar estes dados pro pluguin? Seu código vai ficar mais fácil de ler e mais fácil até de te ajudar, porque atí vai ser apenas saber como tratar os dados do `jSon`.

Comment: Então, vlw pelo toque, consegui resolver aqui, o calendar começa a contar os meses a partir do 0 e meu select traz a partir do 1, e passei para ele pegar o mês -1, no 'start'.